# Does ADFS 2 require signed Saml2 Logout requests?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

Does ADFS 2 require signed SSO Logout requests when using SAML2?  If so, why would Logout require signing yet Login doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADFS2 enforces the SAML spec. This means that it depends on what options you have implemented for a given use case. For example, for SP-Init SLO, a signed  is required when using POST/Redirect binding. For SAML Responses (aka Login), the POST binding mandates signing while using the Artifact/SOAP a signature on the Response is not required as security can be provided in other means.

HTH - Ian